# Understanding the return of a recursive function

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure and am trying to understand why the two functions below are different.

**First**

```
(defn rp [i]
  ((println i)
   (if (> i 3)
     (println "bye")
     (rp (inc i)))))
```

**Second**

```
(defn rp
  ([i] (println i)
       (if (> i 3)
         (println "bye")
         (rp (inc i)))))
```

When I call them with `(rp 0)`, the **first** prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
bye
CompilerException java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/Users/...)
```

and the **second** prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
bye
=> nil
```

Why are they different? Why the **first** function triggers a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Your first example has parens around the body and calls the result of `(println i)` (which is nil) as a function).  e.g. `((println :a) :b)` throws

Comment: Oh, ok, I got it. Thanks, @cfrick.

Comment: @cfrick, I think you could turn your comment into a real answer because you actually answered the question. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example has parens around the body and calls the result of `(println i)` (which is `nil`) as a function. E.g. `((println :a) :b)` throws.  Most likely related to your experiments with the different arities in your second example.